# calling sub makefiles in an easy way fails

Tags: gcc, makefile

I`m using a makefile and call some makefiles in subdirectories.

Can anyony explain me, why this works

```html
 $(MAKE) -C stub
 $(MAKE) -C source
```

but this not

```html
SUBDIRS = stub source

$(SUBDIRS):
 $(MAKE) -C $@
```

First time I`m working with makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not explicitly specify the target(s) to make, [it will use the first target whose name doesn't start with a dot](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-make-Processes-a-Makefile).  Here, that target is `stub`.

Apparently, you expect *all* of the targets of the first rule to be used, but there can only be one default target.

The documentation isn't 100% clear on this.

You will get the desired behavior by prepending the rule:

```
all: $(SUBDIRS)
```